# ERROR: extra data after last expected column - COPY

Tags: postgresql

When I try to import the data with delimiter `|` I receive the error:

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

I am able to load the data if I remove double quote or single quote from the filed which have issue   in the below sample data but my requirement is I need all data without removing any.

This is my copy command:

```
COPY public.dimingredient FROM '/Users//Downloads/archive1/test.txt' 
DELIMITER '|' NULL AS ''  CSV HEADER ESCAPE AS '"'  ;
```

My table:

```
  public.dimingredient
(
    dr_id integer NOT NULL,
    dr_loadtime timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    dr_start timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    dr_end timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    dr_current boolean NOT NULL,
    casnumber character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    ingredientname character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    matchingstrategy character varying(21) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    percentofconfidence double precision,
    disclosurestatus character varying(42) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    issand character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    sandmeshsize character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    sandquality character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    isresincoated character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    isartificial character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT dimingredient_pkey PRIMARY KEY (dr_id)
)
```

my data:

```
5144|2016-07-01 13:34:25.1001891|1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000|9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999|True|93834|"9-octadecenamide,n,n-bis(2-hydroxyethyl)-, (9z)"|"NO CAS MATCH FOUND"||Disclosed|||||

5145|2016-07-01 13:34:25.1001891|1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000|9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999|True|93834|"9-octadecenamide,n,n-bis-2(hydroxy-ethyl)-,(z)""|"NO CAS MATCH FOUND"||Disclosed|||||
```

Comment: The last delimiter has nothing following it? should there be data there as some would be expected ? Can you show us the table you are loading into ?

Comment: @rajkumars - You should edit your post instead of pasting all that in a comment. I added your table DDL along with some formatting, but did not copy over your data as it is truncated and I don't want to misrepresent it. You should, though, update your question with a line or two from your file if it is not sensitive information.

Comment: How is `public.table` defined? How many columns does it have?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  earlier just gave sample copy command.. now I have changed correctly and I have mentioned my test data and table columns how it looks in the below

Comment: @rajkumars - Right now I am looking at 9 questions to the right under "Related" that are all asking the same thing. Have you read any of them to see if your solution is mentioned?

Comment: @nicarus - not any related  my issue

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the empty line in your dample data, I get a different error message with 9.6, to wit:

```
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT:  COPY dimingredient, line 3: "5145|2016-07-01 13:34:25.1001891|1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000|9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999|True|93834|..."
```

Strangely enough, that error message has been there since CSV `COPY` was introduced in version 8.0, so I wonder how your data are different from the data you show above.

The error message is easily explained: There is an odd number of quotation characters (`"`) in the second line.

Since two doubled quotes in a quoted string are interpreted as a single double quote (`"` is escaped as `""`), the fields in the second line are:

```
5145
2016-07-01 13:34:25.1001891
1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999
True
93834
9-octadecenamide,n,n-bis-2(hydroxy-ethyl)-,(z)"|NO CAS MATCH FOUND||Disclosed|||||
```

... and then `COPY` hits the end of file while parsing a quoted string. Hence the error.

The solution is to use an even number of `"` characters per field.

If you need a `"` character in a field, either choose a different `QUOTE` or quote the field and double the `"`.

Comment: I tired all the ways its not working out.. I need all fields without remove any since my data have feet and inches..

Comment: "I tried all the ways and it its not working" is little to go on. You should extend the question and show exactly what you tries and what exact message you got. And there still is the unresolved issue that no version of PostgreSQL will produce the error message you report with the data you show in the question.